# jsonResult: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840

Tags: php, swift

i am a beginner in swift programming an i am working on project where i have to retrieve data from remote mysql database and i have got this error with Json

> jsonResult:  Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}

this is my php file :

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");

$host = 'localhost';
$mysql_username = 'mm';
$mysql_password = 'aa';
$database = 'aa';


$connect  = new mysqli($host, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, 
$database);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()){

die("cannot connect to database".mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo 'Connected successfully';
$latitude = $_REQUEST["latitude"];
$longitude= $_REQUEST["longitude"];


$myArray = array();

$sql = "SELECT * , (6371 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(( $latitude - 
Latitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) +COS($latitude* pi()/180) * COS(Latitude 
* pi()/180) * POWER(SIN(( $longitude - Longitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) 
))) as distance from mosque HAVING distance < 5 order by distance  ";
$result = $connect->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
$myArray = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
print_r($myArray);

} else {
echo "0 results";
}

$myJSON = json_encode($myArray);

echo $myJSON;

$conn->close();
?>
```

and here is my code in swift :

```
import UIKit
class retriveM: NSObject,URLSessionDataDelegate {

 var data : NSMutableData = NSMutableData()

func retrieveNearest(lat:Double,long:Double){

    let url = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: 
"http://mosqueksu.com/mosqueksu/retrieveNearest.php")! as URL )
    url.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "latitude=\(lat),longitude=\(long)"
   // Alamofire.request(.GET,url).responseJSON { response in
    url.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    var session: URLSession!

    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default

    session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: url as URLRequest)

    task.resume()


}



func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data)
{
    self.data.append(data as Data);
}



func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?)
{
    if error != nil
    {
        print("Not Found", error as Any )

    }
    else
    {
        print("Ok")
        self.parseJSON()
    }

}


func parseJSON()
{

   var jsonResult: NSArray = NSArray()

    do
    {
       //  jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data as Data, options: .allowFragments) as! NSArray
        jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data as Data, options: .allowFragments) as! NSArray

        print("jsonResult.count",jsonResult.count)
    }
    catch let error as NSError
    {
        print("jsonResult: ", error)
    }


    var jsonElement: NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
    var contador = 0
    for i in (0..<jsonResult.count)
    {
        jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary

        if let id = jsonElement["OBJECTID"] as? Int,
            let name = jsonElement["ArabicName"] as? String,
            let nameE = jsonElement["EnglishNam"] as? String,
            let lat = jsonElement["Latitude"] as? Double,
            let long = jsonElement["Longitude"] as? Double,
            let status = jsonElement["status"] as? String,
            let distance = jsonElement["distance"] as? Double
        {
            print("id: ", id)
            print("name: ", name)
            print("nameE: ", nameE)
            print("latitude",lat)
            print("longitude",long)
            print ("status",status)
            print ("distance",distance)
        }
    }
}
}
```

i think i got this error from parseJson i tried different methods but it does not work for me , ill appreciate your help .

Comment: What is the response that you get from the server?

Comment: the server return 200 OK

Comment: i meant what data is returned. What response is it that is invalid?

Comment: it suppose to return 141 records from the database and this is some of what i got from postman  :Connected successfullyArray
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [OBJECTID] => 2273
            [ArabicName] => جامع فهد بن سعد
            [EnglishNam] => Fahd bin Saad Mosque
            [Longitude] => 46.65052000
            [Latitude] => 24.73938000
            [status] => grey
            [distance] => 0.14582593565797897
        )

Comment: there is not enough information here for us to help you. the error is telling you that the response has an invalid character. so you need to actually see what the response is. Instead of converting your data to JSON convert it to a string and have a look

Answer (score 0):

actually it's a Api side issue. ie, the response is neither in array nor Dictionary,

so please ask the backend team to create proper json response.

**sample response**

```
{  
   "ReturnCode":"1",
   "ReturnMsg":"Successfull Transaction",
   "Data":{  
      "EmployeeName":"Admin",
      "EmployeeID":1
   }
}
```